# CodeIgniter Routing - 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I'm developping a website using CI and today I'm facing a problem in the admin part.

I've an admin and I can manage users

the structure of my application is:

```
controllers/admin/users.php
```

in users.php I've some functions: `index(), view($id), login(), edit($id)`

```
views/admin/users/index.php
views/admin/users/view.php
views/admin/users/login.php
views/admin/users/edit.php
```

to access the login page the url is:

```
www.mysite.com/admin/login
```

to access the list of users the url is:

```
www.mysite.com/admin/users
```

to view a specific user `(id=5)` the url is:
    `www.mysite.com/admin/users/5`

everything is working well except for the edit function, I got an url when I call    `www.mysite.com/admin/edit/5`

here are my routing rules:

```
$route['admin/users/(:any)'] = 'admin/users/view/$1';
$route['admin/users'] = 'admin/users';

$route['admin/users/login'] = 'admin/users/login';

$route['admin/users/edit/(:num)'] = 'admin/users/edit/$1';

$route['admin'] = 'admin/users/login';
```

I miss something? what is wrong?

Comment: You might wanna look at remapping the function calls.
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping

This can help you avoid using routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting it higher in the sequence, since route are matched top to bottom:

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/users/login';
$route['admin/users'] = 'admin/users';
$route['admin/users/login'] = 'admin/users/login';
$route['admin/users/edit/(:num)'] = 'admin/users/edit/$1';
$route['admin/users/(:any)'] = 'admin/users/view/$1';
```

That `:any` might be catching too much and interfere, I'd leave it as a last catch-all route for all those non specified.

Comment: Prego! :) If you find this answer solves your problem please consider marking it as "accepted" by using the thick mark under the vote count, so to show any future reader the solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['admin/users/(:any)'] = 'admin/users/view/$1';
$route['admin/users'] = 'admin/users';

$route['admin/users/login'] = 'admin/users/login';

$route['admin/edit/(:any)'] = 'admin/edit/view/$1';

$route['admin'] = 'admin/users/login';
```

Try this You might get results!